# IllegalStateException: Exception when I try to jump to my SignUp sheet

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-activity

I am getting an exception at second startActivity(i) statement. My first startActivity(i) statement works fine.

```
public void onBClick(View v){
    EditText a = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.TFUsername);
    String str = a.getText().toString();

    if(v.getId() == R.id.BLogin){
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, new_activ_java.class);
        i.putExtra("username",str+',');
        startActivity(i);
    } else if(v.getId() == R.id.BforSignUp){
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Signup.class);
        startActivity(i);  // I am getting an exception here
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the exception you are getting.

Comment: Yes, without the exception, it's difficult to help you determine what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure Signup is an Activity declared in the Android Manifest. As a convention, append Activity at the end of the class name to indicate that it is indeed an Activity, for instance, SignUpActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the new activity you are trying to start is listed in Android Manifest.xml file.